BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads - Trouble Finding Specific Conversion Data
We've had Google Ads transfers setup with our big query cluster for awhile now. Set it up via https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/google-ads-transfer. It has worked for a lot of our needs but trying to find some other data components needed for reporting. We've also reviewed the data set that's available in Big Query from the Google Ads transfer here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/google-ads-transformation#column_mapping_for_reports as part of our investigation.
We're trying to get conversion data that we need from this data set and have been looking at Google Ads Table Name: AccountConversionStats. We've also looked at this table in Big query (as part of the tables maintained by  BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads): Google Ads Table Name: AdConversionStats. Anywhere we look so far we see  "conversions" and "conv. value" except that the conversion metrics we need are grouped by the time of the conversion/sale (as opposed to the time of the click that led to the conversion which is all we can see that's available via this direct transfer data set so far).
Basically we need these conversion metrics:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/customer#metrics.all_conversions_by_conversion_date
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/customer#metrics.all_conversions_value_by_conversion_date
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/customer#metrics.conversions_by_conversion_date
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/customer#metrics.conversions_value_by_conversion_date
We can pull it via the Google Ads API like so:
SELECT segments.date, customer.id, customer.descriptive_name, campaign.id, campaign.name, segments.conversion_action, segments.conversion_action_name, metrics.all_conversions_by_conversion_date, metrics.all_conversions_value_by_conversion_date, metrics.conversions_by_conversion_date, metrics.conversions_value_by_conversion_date FROM campaign WHERE segments.date = "${dateRange}"
But what we're hoping for is the Google Ads Transfers Service to Big Query provides that directly today. Before we move with a custom solution to pull that via Google Ads API, we wanted to confirm definitively whether or not BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads provides this data.
Can someone that's an expert confirm this please? We just want to make sure we're not missing something.
Thanks!

Note: I asked this same question here: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/BigQuery-Data-Transfer-Service-for-Google-Ads-Trouble-Finding/td-p/733010. But submitting my question here too as suggested by https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-support. Trying to get some help on this ASAP... Thanks y'all!

I wanted to follow up here that after chatting with Google Cloud Platform Technical Support it was confirmed that as of April 2024 BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads today does not provide these data elements. It sounds like it's in their backlog to add though (no ETA). We went with the custom solution to solve our reporting needs.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks for posting this. I was looking for the exact same thing and you probably just saved me hours of fruitless digging!
